# Run app via Xcode in release state?

Tags: ios, xcode

This is a weird issue and I don't know how to phrase the question correctly, but here is the problem.

I have an app on the app store that has a critical problem. What makes this difficult to diagnose and fix however is that when I run the same exact build via Xcode through the debugger, the problem is non-existent. It runs just fine in the debugger.

Is there a way to simulate the archived build in the debugger or something like that? Something must be happening in the archived version that isn't happening in the debug version.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Build Configuration in the scheme from Debug to Release before running it in Xcode?

Comment: What kind of issue is the critical problem? 
Have you tested it on a real device via installing the ipa file?
The ios simulator is alright, but it is not a perfect substitute for the device itself.